# Run controller event after render in Ember without View

Tags: ember.js

I'm new with Ember and what I want to do is execute some initialization with jQuery like this: `Ember.$("select").selectpicker();` to customize default select (it actually inserts div that represents the hidden select). I used to have this code in my Controller:

```
init() {
   this._super();
   Ember.run.schedule("afterRender", this, function() {
      this.send("initializeJQuery");
   }
});
actions: {
   initializeJQuery() {
      Ember.$("select").selectpicker();
   }
}
```

It really initializes my select tags, but when I transition to another route and go back – it rerenders and doesn't want to call initializeJQuery method despite the run method (not runOnce). I use Ember v1.13 and Views are deprecated so I'm looking for alternative way to do this.

Hope for your help.

Comment: views won't be deprecated until version 2.4 of ember...

Comment: **But is here any way to solve problem without View addon?**
> Views are removed from the Ember 2.0 API. However a single release is likely insufficient for large apps to upgrade their entire codebase away from routeable views, and consequently Ember is providing extended support for views via the ember-legacy-views addon. This addon will remain compatible with Ember until v2.4 of the framework is released.

Comment: Yeah use a component. They aren't going anywhere. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init` is only called once, because controllers are singletons. Typically these things are put in `didInsertElement`, preferably in a component. But to show you what's happening consider this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  init: function(){
    console.log("I get called once");
  }
});


App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function(){
    console.log("I get called every time Index is rendered");
  }
});
```

JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xacosekuku/edit?html,css,js,output

Now what you actually want to do is make a component. For instance you can do this:

```
App.SelectPickerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'select',
  didInsertElement: function(){
    this.$().selectpicker();
  }
});
```

Then in your template do:

```
{{#select-picker}}
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
  <option value=3>3</option>
{{/select-picker}}
```

Something like this (but with our jQuery call added): http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xacosekuku/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thank you! I thought about this solution, but was not sure it's the best way.